# Weird behavior when calling load_tests()

Tags: python, unit-testing

When using the new discover feature in Python 2.7, I'm getting a weird error. I have some unit tests that require a bit of extra setup and some member data from a file. I'm trying to add my setup test cases to the current test suite that is passed to `load_tests()`. But because the test suite `tests` already contains the standard tests (including the `TestCase` objects in the current module), the proper setup for the automatically added testcase is not done and I get an AttributeError.

In the code below, `load_tests()` is used to create one test case for each line of data in a csv file. The file has three lines, but for some reason a fourth testcase is being created.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import unittest

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):    
    def setup(self,bar):
        print "Foo.setup()"
        self.bar = bar 
    def runTest(self):
        print self.bar

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    f = open('data.csv')  # data.csv contains three lines: "a\nb\nc"
    for line in f:
        tc = Foo()
        tc.setup(line)
        tests.addTest(tc)
    return tests

unittest.main()
```

When I execute this code, the output shows that 4 tests were executed and one of them failed. The data file only contains three lines, and `Foo.setup()` was only called three times. So `load_tests()` created the three test cases as designed.

```
Foo.setup()
Foo.setup()
Foo.setup()
Ea

.b

.c

.
======================================================================
ERROR: runTest (__main__.Foo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 11, in runTest
    print self.bar
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.002s
```

Is there a way to remove the TestCase that was automatically loaded in the suite? I cannot create a new empty TestSuite because I need all the other tests that are already there. I just want to add these tests to the suite.

Edit: clarified my question and code examples. I was a bit ambiguous before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

If you are always going to instantiate Foo, you could set up bar in the `__init__` method of the class.

```
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar
    def runTest(self):
        print self.bar

f = Foo("some string")
```

I haven't used the `load_tests` pattern directly before -- I usually just rely on nose's auto test discovery, but all of these would work for your setup. If you later wanted to use `TestSuite`s and `unittest`/`nose`'s test autodiscovery, and wanted to use classes, you could use a class factory:

```
def make_foo_case(the_bar):
    class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
        bar = the_bar
        def runTest(self):
            print self.bar
    return Foo

f = (make_testcase("some string"))()
```

or use `type` to subclass foo and set up the element in the members, (essentially the same as the previous) e.g.:

```
class Foo2(object):
    def runTest(self):
        print self.bar

f = (type("Tester2", (Foo2,unittest.TestCase), {"bar":"some string"}))()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however it doesn't address my issue exactly. I think I was being unclear about my question, so I edited it and added more descriptive code.

Comment: @Rusty, what actually happens if you try use the `__init__` method of the class to add bar to the object? Does it still show the same error? That way unittest shouldn't pick up the extra test case (not 100% sure about what you mean in your question by "extra test case" though)

Comment: let me explain what I mean by "extra test case".  The 'load_tests()' function should create three tests, one test for each line of data in the file `data.csv`. But 4 tests are created and executed, one of them being the testcase automatically added in somehow via the normal test loader.  It was my understanding that the presence of `load_tests()` would disable the normal test case loading entirely. But apparently I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ Jeff, if I use the `__init__` method, that 'extra' test case gets created as before, but self.bar == 'runTest'.

Comment: @Rusty I just tried running the file with the `__init__` method (using `python filename.py`) and it ran fine.  Are you running it as part of a larger test suite or something?

Comment: @ Jeff, I am running it in a larger test suite. But running it by itself also generates that extra test case.

Comment: @Rusty - easiest thing to do: define `Foo` in `load_tests` so that `Foo` isn't in the global namespace for the module.

Comment: @Rusty: I have the same issue..Is it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I misunderstand `load_tests()`. According to the Python code in `/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py`, the tests are loaded from the module as normal. Then, if `load_tests()` exist, it is called as well.

```
def loadTestsFromModule(self, module, use_load_tests=True):
    """Return a suite of all tests cases contained in the given module"""
    tests = []
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, case.TestCase):
            tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))

    load_tests = getattr(module, 'load_tests', None)
    tests = self.suiteClass(tests)
    if use_load_tests and load_tests is not None:
        try:
            return load_tests(self, tests, None)
        except Exception, e:
            return _make_failed_load_tests(module.__name__, e,
                                           self.suiteClass)
    return tests
```

So I guess my solution is to accept the extra test case that is created, check for it, and just pass it. Much thanks to Jeff for trying to help me out.